# Google has cached query string based dynamic page, but how/why?

Tags: cache, url, google

I have a multipage form which works largely by posting the form details in query strings to the url. I know this isn't ideal and i've already changed it.

However, what was happening is that google was caching results such as

```
mysite.com/myform?var=var&var2=var2&var3=var3
```

Where the var(s) were populated with form submitted form details.

Any idea why/how this is happening?  Thanks in anticpation.

Comment: Swear somone posted a link to this article: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/04/crawling-through-html-forms.html

Comment: Personally, I think you should post that as the answer and mark it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible that someone posted a link to it with the values embedded.

Google may also [submit simple forms](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/04/crawling-through-html-forms.html) in some circumstances.

Comment: That's all i could think of.  Is there any other way it could happen?

Comment: Depending on the architecture, the crawler could have build the links. In other words - do the users have to select / type things to get there or could the crawler have automated it? An example that Google may crawl would be a dropdown box used for navigation.

Comment: I added that link about Google submitting forms.